# powershell output in shell

Tags: bash, powershell

I am trying to collect an powershell script output in a shell script.

`ssh user@host "powershell Test-Path -Path C:/myfile"`
will if execute in bash just print
`True` . 
If I save it to variable like `ps_result=$(ssh ... >&1)`

ps_result now contains `ps_result=$'False\r'`
which looks weird and I don't know what to do with it in an if statement.

I have two Questions:

- Can I use powershell to print something more useful than whatever $'False\r' is?
- How to handle such an output in an if statement `if [ $ps_result = 'False\r' ];` does not work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$'False\r'` represents a string that contains the literal value `False` followed by a CR character (`\r`).

The `$'...'` notation is a special Bash string notation called [ANSI C-quoting](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting), which supports escape sequences, such as `\r` for CR.

The CR character stems from the fact that Windows PowerShell uses CRLF (`\r\n`) newlines, whereas Bash expects Unix-style LF newlines (`\n`), and therefore considers the CR part of the data when it trims trailing newlines.

You can simply use `$'False\r'` in your `if` statement as well:

```sh
if [[ $ps_result == $'False\r' ]];
```

---

As for preventing the CR characters in the output:

You cannot make PowerShell use LF-only newlines, so the best you can do is to remove the CR instances after the fact; e.g., via [parameter expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe):

```sh
if [[ ${ps_result//$'\r'/} == 'False' ]];
```

Comment: Thank you $'..' this ANSI C-quoting was the missing link I didn't understand. Also the parameter expansion syntax is new to me.

Comment: Glad to hear it, helped, @samst. You're certainly dealing with an unusual combination of tools.